# Converting points back to 3D

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

I have points in a 3D plane that I have converted to a 2D projection using the following method:

```py
import numpy as np

# Calculate axes for 2D projection
# Create random vector to cross
rv = np.add(self.plane.normal, [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
rv = np.divide(rv, np.linalg.norm(rv))
horizontal = np.cross(self.plane.normal, rv)
vertical = np.cross(self.plane.normal, horizontal)

diff2 = np.zeros((len(point23D), 3), dtype=np.float32)
diff2[:, 0] = np.subtract(point23D[:, 0], self.plane.origin[0])
diff2[:, 1] = np.subtract(point23D[:, 1], self.plane.origin[1])
diff2[:, 2] = np.subtract(point23D[:, 2], self.plane.origin[2])

x2 = np.add(np.add(np.multiply(diff2[:, 0], horizontal[0]), np.multiply(diff2[:, 1], horizontal[1])), np.multiply(diff2[:, 2], horizontal[2]))

y2 = np.add(np.add(np.multiply(diff2[:, 0], vertical[0]), np.multiply(diff2[:, 1], vertical[1])), np.multiply(diff2[:, 2], vertical[2]))

twodpoints2 = np.zeros((len(point23D), 3), dtype=np.float32)
twodpoints2[:, 0] = x2
twodpoints2[:, 1] = y2
```

I then do some calculations on these points in 2D space. After that I need to get the points back in 3D space on the same relative position. I have written the following code for that:

```py
# Transform back to 3D
rotation_matrix = np.array([[horizontal[0], vertical[0], -self.plane.normal[0]],
                                    [horizontal[1], vertical[1], -self.plane.normal[1]],
                                    [horizontal[2], vertical[2], -self.plane.normal[2]]])
transformed_vertices = np.matmul(twodpoints, rotation_matrix)
transformed_vertices = np.add(transformed_vertices, self.plane.origin)
```

But this doesn't seem to do the projection correctly, the points projected back in 3D do not lie on the original 3D plane at all. Does anyone know why this is wrong or does anyone have a suggestion that would work better?

In this example I just projected the same points back into 3D to see if it works correctly, which it doesn't. In reality I'll have different points that need to be projected back, but they still need to be in the same plane in 3D space.

Comment: I don't think that is possible at all. Work on a copy of your points.

Comment: The thing is that I need to some calculations in 2D space because they aren't doable in 3D space. What this problem really comes down to is getting the coordinates from around one rotation matrix with a center(in 2D the z-coordinate is just zero) and projecting it around another rotation matrix. I'm pretty sure I've seen this being done before but I can't find it back.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# You have a plane perpendicular to a vector 
# N = np.array([x_N, y_N, z_N]) 
# and passing through a point 
# Q = np.array([x_Q, y_Q, z_Q])

U = np.zeros((3,3))
U[2,:] = N / np.linalg.norm(N)
e = np.array([0,0,0])
e[np.argmin(np.abs(U[0,:]))] = 1

U[0, :] = np.cross(e, U[2,:])
U[0, :]  = U[0, :]  / np.linalg.norm(U[0, :])

U[1, :]  = np.cross(U[2, :], U[0, :])

point2D = (point23D - Q).dot(U)
result_point2D = some_calcs(point2D)
result_point23D = res_point2D.dot(U.transpose())
```